# My scrapy script doesn't seem to be calling the parse_item method

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and my first exercise is to scrape a certain page on 6pm site:

1. Get the url of each product on the initial page
2. Enter the link and scrape product information (Reference, description, price, etc..)
3. Go back to the inital page and go to the next product, etc.

It seems like I get the Products URLS from the inital page, and then I can't seem the get the `parse_item` method to be called. I have tried to read and find similar problems, but maybe because I am new to this, I couldn't comprehend why it's not working. I have tried using the Rule method, and with the same results. 
Can somebody please help me? I have been trying to resolve this issue for 3 days now. Thanks.

Here is a copy of my script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from esourcing.items import EsourcingItem
from scrapy.http import Request
import re


class SixpmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sixpmsouq'
    allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = ('https://www.6pm.com/a2-by-aerosoles-women- 
shoes/CK_XAVoC0iPAAQHiAgQBCxgykgMLWzcwIFRPIDEwMF0.zso?
s=recentSalesStyle/desc/',)


    def parse(self, response):
        html = response.body

        for href in response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="url"]/@href'):
            url = "http://www.6pm.com"+ href.extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)


    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = EsourcingItem()
        item['reference'] = response.xpath('//*[text()="SKU: #"]/text() [2]').extract()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your [`allowed_domains`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains) attribute is filtering off the requests that you generate in `self.parse`.

If you check your spider logs, you'll see a message saying that the `OffsiteMiddleware` filtered your request, like this:

```
DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.6pm.com': <GET ....>
```

Fix it by changing such attribute to: `['6pm.com']`

```
class SixpmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sixpmsouq'
    allowed_domains = ['6pm.com']
```

In case you are wondering why the first request (from `start_urls`) succeeded, that's because the URLs from `start_urls` (or `start_requests`) are not subject to such filters.